# Why a http:// request turns to file:/// in a cordova wrapped app?

Tags: javascript, html, cordova

I am working on a web single page app which heavily uses ajax requests and works properly inside a desktop browser. But when I put it inside the cordova wrapper in XCode and run it again in the emulator or on the iPhone, for some reason, instead of requests like `http://myhost:3000/api/login` I see `file:///api/login` and obviously it fails.
What can be the reason?

Comment: I guess you trying open a file directly rather than from server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A PhoneGap application runs on a `file:` page, and the request is probably for the absolute path `/api/login`, so the absolute path resolves to `file:///api/login`.

I assume your code previously ran on a `http://myhost:3000` page, where the absolute path resolved to `http://myhost:3000/api/login`.

If you want to make a request to a host in PhoneGap, you must specify the host explicitly in the path. To allow Ajax access to a host, you may need to [explicitly whitelist](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.9.0/guide_whitelist_index.md.html) it.